# Why does getMapCapabilities cause a NullPointerException when called in onMapReady?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm checking whether I can use `AdvancedMarkers` on a given device by calling `getMapCapabilities`.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
    MapCapabilities mapCapabilities = googleMap.getMapCapabilities();
```

However, this crashes every time with a `NullPointerException`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotNull(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:1)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MapCapabilities.<init>(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.2.0:1)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.getMapCapabilities(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.2.0:1)
```

The map isn't null so I'm confused what is failing the `checkNotNull` condition.

I am running on a virtual device but I still wouldn't have expected it to crash.

Comment: Did you make sure that you were running on the New Map renderer? I just tested on my end the getMapCapabilities method but I can't seem to see the error. Can you try to put up a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or also file this as an issue in the Public Issue Tracker? You can do it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/support

Comment: It is running the new map renderer. I managed to get it working by moving my code around as explained in my answer - but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, moving `getMapCapabilities()` out of `onMapReady` caused it to work okay. I'm not entirely sure why, as the whole point of `onMapReady` is that the map is... ready.

I also found that it's not possible to chain `map.getMapCabilities().isAdvancedMarkersAvailable()` without the same error occurring. I had to first get the `MapCababilities`, then separately check if `AdvancedMarkers` are available.

All in all, it's a bit of a weird problem, and it may well be linked to the fact that it's running on an emulator. The documentation doesn't really shed any light on this.